# JavaScript: drag and drop using Scriptaculous and Prototype

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm following their tutorial: http://www.stillnetstudios.com/drag-and-drop-sort-order-with-scriptaculous/

The example shown doesn't work. I've also used their code on my own web page and the drag and drop doesn't seem to be working.
Not sure if I can ask this here! If anyone can be of help, I'd appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples on linked page are not working because the libraries hosted on the site are not found:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://www.stillnetstudios.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/javascript/scriptaculous.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://www.stillnetstudios.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/javascript/scriptaculous_sort_demo.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://www.stillnetstudios.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/javascript/prototype.js

The code itself is working. Have a look **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/uQVyU/)**.

Make sure that scripts on your page are properly loaded. Look for the error messages using your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Oh! Okay :) Thanks. I also took out the front '/' when referencing my javascript files and it works now (my fault).